# JS classList property and getElementsByClassName method fallback functions

Tags: javascript

the HTML DOM classList Property:

```
   document.getElementById("x").classList.add("y");
```

and HTML DOM getElementsByClassName() Method

```
document.getElementsByClassName("x");
```

are not supported by older versions of browsers. how to check if a browser supports them? and is there any fallback functions that can replace them in case they are not supported

Comment: Try not to ask three questions at the same time in future.

Comment: document.getElementById() is supported from IE 5.5 so I guess the problem is only document.getElementsByClassName() which is not supported prior IE9. Use your favorite search engine and give it a go with "document.getElementsByClassName polyfill"

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByClassName` has a very good support.

`classList` also, but you can fallback with `className` which is a `String` not a `DOMTokenList`.

consider using `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` instead.